# Strange behaviour on LCD monitor that doesn't turn on

Tags: display, power-supply, power

This monitor will only turn on on 1 out of 8 or 10 attempts at pressing the "power" button, only after I had disconnected and reconnected it to the power line before each attempt, i.e.:

1. Connect the monitor to the power line.
2. Press the "power" button to attempt to turn it on.
3. If it doesn't turn on, disconnect it and repeat from step 1.

Like I said, I have to do this 8 to 10 times before it finally turns on. I believe it can't be a faulty button just because pressing it 10 or even 100 times just doesn't make it work, I have to disconnect and reconnect it.

What could be the problem? Is there any fix or to the trash it goes?

Comment: Could be bad caps, or a bad transisitor. Would cracking it open and doing a visual inspection be an option?

Comment: I think so, but not for now since I am away from my tools, maybe tomorrow at work. Is there something I should look for specifically, or is it something I can see easily?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd check to see if its the backlight (you can get replacement inverters online) with a flashlight - if you see an image, you basically have it narrowed down there.

Otherwise, its bad capasitors.

I'd note that bad capacitors are symptomatic of other issues and its going to be a *massive* timesink fixing these. I have a monitor with a near complete capasitor replacement that's not usable cause the backlight power unit may have a bad transistor as well.

You  want to look for *domed*, *leaky* or otherwise flawed capasitors, and replace them with quality capasitors (I've had reasonable luck with off brand cheapies, but [this is good advice](http://www.eevblog.com/forum/chat/capacitor-replacement-for-lcd-tv-power-supply/?PHPSESSID=266970f9f7ed23eb7a284ca130e627e1). There's a *ton* of great guides worth looking at - this is the one I [used](http://neoxy-yx.blogspot.sg/2011/12/tips-and-tricks-on-repairing-lcd.html).

I personally would recommend finding an oldschool repair guy to do this since they'd already have the parts and skills needed. In my case I'm currently stuck at a blown transistor and am debating converting my old screen to LEDs ;)

Comment: I understand and I completely agree with you, maybe I'd send it to the electronics guy but seeing as it may be as costly as 50% of a new one, I think I'll just wait for the paycheck to buy at least a 19" one. I don't know how old is this one but its ratio is 4:3 so go figure... Thank you!

Comment: Then its really old. I was fixing mine since I have an old system I want to boot up that dosen't do widescreen. Its DIYable for very little money but its a timesink. I've been working on and off on that particular screen over 2-3 years ;p

Comment: Wow, that sure is a lot of time, I really started to use this one since, well, it was the only one that looked decent among all the other CRTs I had there. But it's causing more issues, I'll just abandon it again where it was.